# How do I run a PowerShell Workflow only once?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have the below powershell workflow script which is part of a larger script which executes at every reboot of the system, I need this to run and edit the files only once. Please let me know how to achieve that. Thank you.

```
#=============================Edit Oracle DB files==============================
workflow Edit-Dbfiles {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]$oracleFilePaths,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1)]$newHostname
  )
 
  ForEach ($filePath in $oracleFilePaths) {
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $filePath)) {
      Write-Warning "$filePath does not exist`r`n"
    }
    else {
      Write-Host "Modifying hostname in $filePath"
      $tempFilePath = "$env:HOMEDRIVE\temp\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
      $hostPattern = "(?<=\(HOST = )[^)]+"
      (Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $hostPattern, $newHostname | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath
      Remove-Item -Path $filePath
      Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath
      Write-Host "Modified $filePath with the new hostname - $newHostname"
    }
  }
}

Edit-Dbfiles -oracleFilePaths $oracleFilePaths -newHostname $newHostname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the following changes in Edit-Dbfiles logic may work for you:

1. Created some file(i.e. "executed.txt") at the end of the execution of "Edit-Dbfiles" and store it somewhere in the system where it will not be accidentally deleted, after `Write-Host "Modified $filePath with the new hostname - $newHostname"`
2. Add verification that "executed.txt" exists at the beginning of the workflow and does not run it if exists

Comment: Is there a better way to do it if I am using powershell functions?